# Jquery ui sortable change event not firing - inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm creating an sortable/swappable app with Jquery ui sortable and happens that the `change` function is acting inconsistent, it fires sometimes, sometimes not. Sometimes it fires if I drag one element down, but not when I drag it up and vice-versa. When it happens I can see the `.ui-sortable-handle` element changing it's style in the console, like `top: 200px;` but the event doesn't fires.

```
this.$_options.sortable({
        axis: "y",
        containment: "parent",
        delay: 100,
        tolerance: 'intersect',
        grid: [ 0, 44 ],
        change: function(event, ui){
            console.log('hello');
        }
    });
```

The element receiving `.sortable` is part of a larger object, it's just a dom cache variable, like: `this.$_options = this.$_id.find('.orderable-options');`

Comment: Could you provide a working example at jsfiddle or something of the like?

Comment: @Twisty sure, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/tmybsvz9/
Open your console to see when the change event is fired and when it's not. Play with it a little bit and you'll see what I'm talking about.
The documentation is in portuguese, it's my main language, sorry for that.
The .sortable() function is in the RENDER method, at the end of the object.